# Get the instantaneous value of y, pointed to by the mouse, on the graph using apexcharts

Tags: angular, events, coordinates, apexcharts, candlesticks

I am using apexchart to show the operation of a cryptocurrency on a chart. I want to be able to click on the graph and capture the current y value. This value is not necessarily in the series. I checked that the "event" property has a lot of information, but I didn't find the value of "y" in the mouse position on the graph. Can anyone tell me if it exists?

I hope to use the value of e to simulate a trade.
Thanks